# Query to PostgreSQL returns a result with 1 column and 0 rows?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I am accessing the PostgreSQL server with libpq. My query looks like this ('Africa' is any string, `column_2` and `column_3` are both valid names and both queries return fine when executed from psql prompt):

```
SELECT column_2 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE column_1='Africa' AND column_2 IS NOT NULL 
    LIMIT 1;
```

I get a result of 1 row and 1 column. Then some time later I change `column_2` to `column_3` and issue:

```
SELECT column_3 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE column_1='Africa' AND column_3 IS NOT NULL 
    LIMIT 1;
```

Now `PQnfields()` returns 1 as expected, But `PQntuples` returns 0!
So now for some reason there are 0 rows, which of course breaks a call to `data = PQgetvalue(resuls, 0, 0)`

What is a possible source of error and why would it even return 1 column if there are no rows?

Comment: What is the problem with a result that has 1 (or 2, 3, 10 ...) columns and no rows? It is perfectly valid on postgres side.

Comment: If there is no data that matches `column_1='Africa' AND column_3 IS NOT NULL` then there are 0 rows to return. The structure (number and types of the columns) of returned rows is defined by the query itself. This structure does not depend on number of rows returned.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko yes, I basically had a typo. I guess that its according to some standard that PostgreSQL decides to return 1 column for a failed query instead of 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query has one column but zero rows:

```
SELECT a as col1
FROM generate_series(1,2) a
WHERE false;
```

Nonetheless, it still has the same result type as if it did not have the `WHERE FALSE`. It just has zero rows.

This is why I prefer to think of fields and records, not "columns" and "rows". The latter leads you to think about it like a spreadsheet, but a relation is not a spreadsheet table. It still has a well-defined structure *even if it is empty*.

So, if `PQntuples` returns zero, don't try to access results that don't exist. It's normal and acceptable for a query to return zero rows. It can be quite handy; for example, you can still use `PQftype` to determine the data type that any results that *were* returned would be, if there were any.

The underlying reason it works this way is that PostgreSQL answers a query in a few stages (simplifying by assuming v3 protocol parse/bind/describe/execute execution, and skipping irrelevant steps):

- "Query parsed OK"
- "Parameters received OK"
- "Query result structure will be (colname coltype, colname coltype, ...)"
- "Query executed OK"
- "Query result rows are ..."

So even if there aren't any result rows, we already know the structure they would've had.

Comment: Good to know! This is why it returned 1 column instead of 0, the result has the right format (number of fields) but just does not contain any rows (records).